# Ant Design - Reactjs: radio buttons group

Tags: reactjs, radio-button, antd, radio-group

I am newbie, and I have a reactjs antd issue with radio buttons group. Is there any way to have a bigger gap or space between each radio button? For example one radio button on left side of the page and second on the other side. https://codesandbox.io/s/radio-group-antd-4-19-4-forked-134cps?from-embed ignore the slider in code please.

Comment: You can use LESS or CSS3 to style your form group

Answer (score 2):

use ant Row with justify content "space-between"

```
<Radio.Group
  onChange={(e) => {
    console.log("radio checked", e.target.value);
    setcurrentValueRadio(e.target.value);
  }}
  value={currentValueRadio}
  style={{ width: "100%" }}
>
  <Row justify="space-between">
    <Radio value={1}>2021</Radio>
    <Radio value={2}>2022</Radio>
  </Row>
</Radio.Group>;
```

Comment: according to antd docs: "only col should be placed directly in row" - https://ant.design/components/grid#outline

Answer (score 1):

Use can use Antd grid to align the radio buttons

```js
import { Radio, Row, Col } from "antd";

<Radio.Group
        onChange={(e) => {
          console.log("radio checked", e.target.value);
          setcurrentValueRadio(e.target.value);
        }}
        value={currentValueRadio}
        style={{ width: "100%" }}
      >   
        <Row>
          <Col span={12} align="left">
            <Radio value={1}>2021</Radio>
          </Col>
          <Col span={12} align="right">
            <Radio value={2}>2022</Radio>
          </Col>
        </Row>       
</Radio.Group>
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

If you make a css class then you can style your react components.
Here's how I did it in your sandbox:

```
// in index.css
.radioLeft {
  right: 0%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```
// in index.js
<Radio value={2} className='radioLeft'>2022</Radio>
```

This will put the 2022 radio at the very right side of the screen, on the same y-dimension as the first radio button. You can change the 'right' value in 'index.css' to adjust it as you please.